Safety considerations for designing Mains Voltage Sensing Circuit
I'm looking to design a circuit to measure AC mains voltage and current for protection purposes. I'm considering using the ADS131E0 ADC by Texas. The IC is made with power-line monitoring in mind.
On Figure 60 of its datasheet, in the pdf page 58, available here, there is a diagram of the recommended Voltage Sensing Circuitry:

In this diagram, there is no isolation between the mains voltage live and the measuring circuitry containing the ADC and, presumably an MCU. I understand that multiple resistors should be used to avoid a single point of failure in case a resistor shorts out as well as to split the load between them for dissipating purposes. I also understand that the geometry of the resistors is important because pads at different voltages should be kept at the appropriate distance. So let's pretend the circuit has all the RDivs disposed in a line geometry.
However, I find many recommendations online to use an isolation transformer such as the ZMPT101B to provide isolation between the mains voltage live and the measuring low voltage circuitry. According to the ZMPT101B's datasheet, the isolation voltage is 4000V.
So, my questions (which are to be considered more like food for thought because I'm not just looking for direct answers but to understanding all the reasons behind each possible answer for each possible scenario):
So let's say I design the circuit as recommended by Texas, not using a transformer and only using Resistors. Let's assume the total working voltage of all resistors in series combined is 4000V. Let's also assume I place the resistors in a line geometry, keeping maximum distance between pads at different voltages. Will it be as safe as using a ZMPT101B transformer? I understand it might depend on the scenario, so let's consider multiple scenarios:

The entire board is enclosed in a plastic box with no risk of human contact with any parts of the circuit, not even the ADC circuitry. So electrocution shouldn't play a role here, the only risk I see is the possibility of a fire hazard.

The entire board is enclosed in a plastic box but this time it is connected through ethernet to a switch. Now the other end of the ethernet cable can be touched by a human which is hard but not impossible to come into contact with the metal parts, which are connected to the MCU and, therefore, the ADC.

Lastly, let's consider that a human may come into contact with metal parts that are connected to the ADC. This is obviously the worst scenario, but I just want to know if those resistors should be considered as safe as using a transformer for providing insulation. Would this last setup also be considered safe according to legal safety standards?


Also, what are the disadvantages of using a transformer? One I can think of is the transformer catching noise from switching components of the circuit such as SMPSes that will definitely be there to power the MCU and the ADC. Is this an actual drawback? What other drawbacks may potentially exist?

"So, my questions (which are to be considered more like food for thought" - EESE is a place for asking specific questions that can be given definitive answers rather than open-ended discussions.

@Finbarr Definitive answers are also welcome, I was just trying to say that pros and cons type answers and deep explanations of the underlying concepts are welcome :)

What you can do as a physicist and get to work, and what you can do in a given legal jurisdiction, and what you can get covered by insurance, are all very different things. I could advise on resistor ratings to make things work, but would your insurer still cover you if made a claim for a totally unrelated cause, and they found this home-built non-approved mains-connected doohicky on the premises?
